# AWS API Gateway with Lambda proxy gives empty event data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have three separate AWS account, Test, QA and Production and I am using AWS API Gateway which is setup to trigger Lambdas.
I had an older version of the setup working fine in all three environments but deploying a new version to Test made the solution stop working as the {event} data sent from API GW to the Lambda function is now empty `{}`.

In QA and Production the {event} object contains the resource, path, etc.

I did a rollback to the previous version in Test and have compared the export YAML files from the three environments and they are all identical (apart from the environment tags). Despite the rollback (I am using Serverless) the {event} object is still empty in the Test account...

The API is a GET with a {proxy+} path and the Lambda is Node.js.

In CloudWatch I can also see that {event} is just empty `{}` in Test now.

Why would the event be empty in just one environment?
[image]

Comment: how did you solve this? @Anders